# Perl: How to avoid regex UTF-8 errors when reading from middle of file

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

Reading a utf8 encoded file after seek as in `open(FILE, '<:utf8', $file) or die; seek(FILE, $readFrom, 0); read(FILE, $_, $size);` sometimes "breaks up" a unicode char so the beginning of the read string is not valid UTF-8.

If you then do e.g. `s{^([^\n]*\r?\n)}{}i` to strip the incomplete first line, you get "Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal)" errors.

How to fix this?

One solution, listed in [How do I sanitize invalid UTF-8 in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234386/how-do-i-sanitize-invalid-utf-8-in-perl) is to remove all invalid UTF-8 chars:

```
tr[\x{9}\x{A}\x{D}\x{20}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}][]cd;
```

However, to search the entire string seems like overkill, as it is only the first byte(s) in the read string that can be broken.

Can anyone suggest a way to strip only an initial invalid char (or make the above substitution not die on malformed UTF-8)?

Comment: apply your `tr` to only the first character?

Comment: This shouldn't happen, see ``perldoc -f read`` *Note the characters: ...By default all filehandles operate on on bytes, but...if the filehandle has been opened with the ":utf8" I/O layer the I/O will operate on UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters, not bytes*  Please give a minimal example of this happening

Comment: That `tr` strips out at least 29 valid characters!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the stream as bytes, strip out partial characters at the start, determine where the last full character ends, then decode what's left.

```
use Encode qw( STOP_AT_PARTIAL );
use Fcntl  qw( SEEK_TO );

my $encoding = Encode::find_encoding('UTF-8');

open(my $FILE, '<:raw', $file) or die $!;
seek($FILE, $readFrom, SEEK_TO) or die $!;
my $bytes_read = read($FILE, my $buf, $size);
defined($bytes_read) or die $!;

$buf =~ s/^[\x80-\xBF]+//;

my $str = $encoding->decode($buf, STOP_AT_PARTIAL);
```

If you want to read more, use the 4-arg form of `read`, and don't skip anything at the start this time.

```
my $bytes_read = read($FILE, $buf, $size, length($buf));
defined($bytes_read) or die $!;

$str .= $encoding->decode($buf, STOP_AT_PARTIAL);
```

Related reading: [Convert UTF-8 byte stream to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31504252/589924)

Comment: `s/^\x80+//`? That's not how UTF-8 works. Continuation bytes can be stripped with `s/^[\x80-\xBF]+//`.

Comment: @nwellnhof, ack! of course! (I knew that, as evidenced by my Answer to the linked question.) Fixed.